# SQL ORACLE Fetch reversal date transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

Columns: item_number, category_id, transaction_number, transaction_effective_date

I am trying to get the records from my table "transactions" of all backdated transactions.

So when transaction_number column is sorted in ascending order partitioned by item_number and category_id and if the transaction_effective date is backdated(desc), sql should fetch all 4 columns

Eg.

```
| ITEM_NUM | CATEGORY_NUM   |TRANSACTION_NUMBER|TRANSACTION_EFF_DATE
| -------- | -------------- |------------------|-------------------
| 100      | 55             |   1              |01-Jan-2022
| 100      | 55             |   2              |02-Jan-2022
| 100      | 55             |   3              |25-Feb-2022
| 100      | 55             |   4              |18-Feb-2022
| 100      | 55             |   5              |05-Mar-2022
| 200      | 12             |   1              |18-Feb-2022
| 200      | 12             |   2              |20-Feb-2022
```

transaction_number 4 for item_number 100 is backdated so item number 100 and its category_number 55 should be returned.

Expected result:

```
| ITEM_NUM | CATEGORY_NUM
| -------- | ------------
| 100      | 55
```

I am fairly new to using lag function so not able to tget it right

Comment: Please post sample data ant desired output in tabular text format along with a description of that output and your current code

Comment: You mention `LAG`, which is the appropriate function. This is the function you need. What about is it `LAG` that you don't understand? Have you tried to merely select all rows with their previous row's date? Please show your attempt.

Comment: What exactly do you want to return? Just the number 100? Or the one row with transaction_number 4? Or all rows for item_num 100? Or what else?

Comment: Yes, I want it listed - Even if there is 1 transaction that occurs before previous transaction date

Comment: I wnat item_number and category_number to be listed: 100, 55 in this case

Comment: Okay, I've added the expected result to the request and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return all rows for which exists a row with a lower transaction number but a higher date for the same item.

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.item_num = t.item_num
  and t2.transaction_number < t.transaction_number
  and t2.transaction_eff_date > t.transaction_eff_date
)
order by item_num, transaction_number;
```

If you only want the item number and category number, then:

```
select distinct item_num, category_num
from mytable t
where exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.item_num = t.item_num
  and t2.transaction_number < t.transaction_number
  and t2.transaction_eff_date > t.transaction_eff_date
)
order by item_num, category_num;
```

Same query with `LAG`. It only detects mismatches between two consecutive rows, but this suffices for the given task.

```
select distinct item_num, category_num
from 
(
  select
    t.*, 
    lag(transaction_eff_date) over (partition by item_num order by transaction_eff_date) as prev_date
  from mytable t2
) with_prev_date
where date < prev_date
order by item_num, category_num;
```

Comment: Wow! The one without lag worked perfectly fine. Why did I have to bring in lag and complicate it at the first place. Thank you so much!